# Using DataBinder for casting the whole object in one step

Tags: asp.net-mvc, casting, databinder

Is it possible to cast the whole object using `DataBinder.Eval()` instead of casting it by property. e.g.:

```
// instead of this
var p = new Person();
p.FirstName = Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName"));
p.Age = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Age"));
...

// use something like this in one step
var p = DataBinder.Eval<Person>(Container.DataItem);
```

Comment: why on earth would u use such a code in asp.net mvc3 when it provides out of the box modelbinding. have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/02/25/asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid I use it within view to process the value that is provided by DevExpress control. I _have to_ deal with `Container.DataItem`.